# Are there any traditions that believe in the complete cessation of miracles?

Tags: denomination-survey, miracles, cessationism

As I have learned from [this question of mine](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10020/do-cessationists-believe-that-there-are-no-modern-miracles), the general consensus is that Cessationists do *not* believe in the cessation of **all** miracles. This lead me to wonder what to call the people that do believe in the complete cessation of all kinds of miracles or supernatural events.

Are there any significant traditions that believe that all miracle-working has stopped? If so, what are they? What would the general idea of total cessation be called?
<sub>(Note: I expect the answer to the second question to be a small set, if any, so I don't think it's a listy question.)</sub>

Comment: Wouldn't these folks essentially be Deists?

Comment: @waxeagle: Hmmm...not quite. Deists believe that God started the universe and then laid back in His easy chair. This is asking about a similar perspective, but located in the first few centuries AD.

Comment: You're looking for one word to define this idea?  Why aren't you happy with the sentence:  "People who believe all miracle working has stopped"?

Comment: I think "total" cessationists would argue that God works faith in the hearts of people, which is a miracle. But that is about all he really does. It's functional deism. God,” said Pascal, “instituted prayer in order to lend His creatures the dignity of causality.” Such is not the theology of strict "total" cessationism. It's a spiritual worldview of God being essentially an absentee landlord, except in cases of regeneration and stimulating the soul through Scriptural reminders to do good works.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this message from the Church of Christ](http://www.renaroadchurchofchrist.com/miracles_church_of_christ.htm), miracles have ceased completely.
I don't know that this fits the bill of "major traditions".  From what I can see, it's not just a single independent non-denominational Church.  [The website does list several of them](http://www.renaroadchurchofchrist.com/area_congregations_of_the_church.htm).  I suppose it depends on where you draw the line at "significant".  Interestingly enough, a Google search for "all miracles have ceased" turns up a number of [insert city name] Church of Christ hits.

And they're not the only group.  I also found [this sermon](http://www.bassfishing.org/thebiblespeaks/Articles/Miracles/mircease2.htm) preaching the same message.  I can't make out any recognizable denomination here.  They simply seem to refer to themselves as "The Church".

[Bible Truths.Net](http://www.bibletruths.net/archives/BTARO76.htm) teaches the same thing.

Apparently there ***are*** those out there that believe in a ***complete*** cessation of miracles, which is really only one step away from the teaching outlined in my answer to your other question.

As I look further into this, it turns out that "Cessationist" is a term a bit like "Fundamentalist".  It means different things depending on who's supplying the definition.  Based on that, although on every site I've run across, "Cessationism" referes to the belief in the end, specifically, of the *Charismatic* gifts. (Speaking in tongues, faith healing, resurrection, prophecy, etc.), not all miracles.

As for the ones that believe in total cessation, I've been searching for a while, trying to find a proper term for the belief, and I can't find a single one.  They're not referred to as "cessationists" by anyone that's cite-worthy.  I've seen the term used in this context on two Tripod websites and a few blogs, but nothing  official that would stand up to the normal test for accepted external source references.

So back to an attempt at an answer, **there do appear to be groups, and they may represent a "significant" portion of Christianity, that do believe in the complete cessation of miracles after the New Testament times.**  But I'm no closer than you were in finding a proper name for them, or their belief, other than an unofficial "Total Cessationists" (which I just made up and doesn't count.).

Comment: +1 for total cessationists.  Probably is a good term.  However even here I bet the 'total' varies widely.  Some of these believers may strongly believe that God often uses purely natural means under his providential care to perform many miracles.  'Miracle' may mean something that clearly violates what only seems natural.  Many might think God works our everything to the benfit of his children, and that itself is highly miraculous, though disguised under what seems like just chance. I think they mean the overwhelming unexplainable miracles as a 'miracle', like instant healing of leprosy.