# What is the Cessationist view on miracle reports surrounding St. Macarius of Egypt?

Tags: church-history, early-church, saint, spiritual-gifts, cessationism

[Macarius of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macarius_of_Egypt):

> Macarius of Egypt (c. 300 – 391) was a Coptic Christian monk and hermit. He is also known as Macarius the Elder or Macarius the Great.

> St. Macarius was born in Lower Egypt. A late tradition places his birthplace in the village of Shabsheer (Shanshour), Roman Egypt around 300 AD. At some point before his pursuit of asceticism, Macarius made his living smuggling saltpeter in the vicinity of Nitria, a vocation which taught him how to survive in and travel across the wastes in that area.[1]

--

**Some highlights from a few sources**

According to this [source](https://www.stmacariusoca.org/about/st-macarius-the-great-of-egypt/):

> **Dweller of the desert and angel in the body**
> **you were shown to be a wonder-worker, our God-bearing Father Macarius**.
> **You received heavenly gifts through fasting, vigil, and prayer**:
> **healing the sick and the souls of those drawn to you by faith**.
> Glory to Him who gave you strength!
> Glory to Him who granted you a crown!
> **Glory to Him who through you grants healing to all**!

According to this [source](https://www.ecatholic2000.com/macarius/untitled-02.shtml):

> **As a bride is not satisfied with her bridegroom’s gifts, but craves for the bridegroom himself, “so the soul … receives as an earnest from the Spirit gifts of healings, it may be, or of knowledge, or of revelation, but it is not satisfied with these, until it attains the complete union, namely charity, which can never change nor fail, and which sets those who have longed for it free from passion and from agitation”** (XLV. 7).

According to this [source](https://www.oca.org/saints/lives/2013/01/19/100226-venerable-macarius-the-great-of-egypt) (see bold text):

> Until his parents died, Saint Macarius used his remaining substance to help them and he began to **pray fervently that the Lord might show him a guide on the way to salvation**. The Lord sent him an experienced Elder, who lived in the desert not far from the village. **The Elder accepted the youth with love, guided him in the spiritual science of watchfulness, fasting and prayer**, and taught him the handicraft of weaving baskets. After building a separate cell not far from his own, the Elder settled his disciple in it.

> **Saint Macarius survived many demonic attacks against him**. Once, he was carrying palm branches for weaving baskets, and a devil met him on the way and wanted to strike him with a sickle, but he was not able to do this. He said, “Macarius, I suffer great anguish from you because I am unable to vanquish you. I do everything that you do. **You fast**, and I eat nothing at all. **You keep vigil**, and I never sleep. **You surpass me only in one thing: humility**.”

> When the saint reached the age of forty, he was ordained to the priesthood and made the head of the monks living in the desert of Skete. During these years, Saint Macarius often visited with Saint Anthony the Great, receiving guidance from him in spiritual conversations. Abba Macarius was deemed worthy to be present at the death of Saint Anthony and he received his staff. **He also received a double portion of the Anthony’s spiritual power, just as the prophet Elisha once received a double portion of the grace of the prophet Elias**, along with the mantle that he dropped from the fiery chariot.

> **Saint Macarius worked many healings**. **People thronged to him from various places for help and for advice, asking his holy prayers**. **All this unsettled the quietude of the saint. He therefore dug out a deep cave under his cell, and hid there for prayer and meditation**.

> **Saint Macarius attained such boldness before God that, through his prayers, the Lord raised the dead**. Despite attaining such heights of holiness, he continued to preserve his unusual humility.

> During the years of the reign of the Arian emperor Valens (364-378), Saint Macarius the Great and Saint Macarius of Alexandria were subjected to persecution by the followers of the Arian bishop Lucius. They seized both Elders and put them on a ship, sending them to an island where only pagans lived. **By the prayers of the saints, the daughter of a pagan priest was delivered from an evil spirit. After this, the pagan priest and all the inhabitants of the island were baptized**. When he heard what had happened, the Arian bishop feared an uprising and permitted the Elders to return to their monasteries.

> **Abba Macarius spent sixty years in the wilderness, being dead to the world. He spent most of his time in conversation with God, often in a state of spiritual rapture**. But he never ceased to weep, to repent and to work. The saint’s profound theological writings are based on his own personal experience. Fifty Spiritual Homilies and seven Ascetic Treatises survive as the precious legacy of his spiritual wisdom. Several prayers composed by Saint Macarius the Great are still used by the Church in the Prayers Before Sleep and also in the Morning Prayers.

---

**Question**

What is the Cessationist view on the miracle reports surrounding St. Macarius of Egypt?

Are these reports credible?

If the stories are true, would they be compatible or consistent with a Cessationist worldview?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate of one of your older more general questions?

Comment: @curiousdannii - the closest question I can think of is this one: [Do Cessationists reject Lee Strobel and Craig S. Keener's books collating modern-day miracle reports?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86098/50422) - closely related, but not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: I like this question, but I don't think there's any standard cessationist view on St. Macarius in particular. There might be a standard repertoire of responses to accounts *like this*, but that pushes the question closer to something like the question you linked - a general account of wonder-workers.